# i want to display my api data in a bar chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, bar-chart

how can i display my api data in a bar chart ?

this is my api response

```
 {
  "jour1": 0,
  "jour2": 1,
  "jour3": 1,
  "jour4": 0,
  "jour5": 0,
  "jour6": 1,
  "jour7": 4
 }
```

this is how i fetch my api data, it works with pie chart and different response, but now i can't find how to use bar chart

pie chart fetch

```
  final response = await 
  http.get(Uri.parse("url"));
      final js = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final Map<String, double> d = {
        'absent' : js['all'].toDouble() - js['present'].toDouble(),
        'present' : js['present'].toDouble(),
      };
     return d;
```

This is the pieChart i used, it requires a map of data

```
 PieChart(
                            dataMap: ss.data,

                            chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.7,
                            legendOptions: LegendOptions(
                                legendPosition: LegendPosition.bottom,
                                legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                )
                            ),
                            chartValuesOptions: ChartValuesOptions(
                                chartValueStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Colors.black
                                )
                            )
                        ),
```

that's why i tried the same in bar chart, but i can't find a barchart that uses map as its data.

```
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url"));
final js = jsonDecode(response.body);
final Map<String, int> d = {
  'jour1' : js['jour1'],
  'jour2' : js['jour2'],
  'jour3' : js['jour3'],
  'jour4' : js['jour4'],
  'jour5' : js['jour5'],
  'jour6' : js['jour6'],
  'jour7' : js['jour7'],
};

return d;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure which package you are using for the PieChart, if any, but looking at https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple it seems you can use a map or custom object for this bar chart. I would highly recommend creating a custom object for your API data, but it might not be necessary with this package.

Comment: i tried this barchart package but it didn't work with map, it needs a charts.serie type of data. 
i got this error when i tried it 
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Series<dynamic, String>>'

Comment: In this case, I think it would be best to convert your data into a list of objects. I did some testing with the bar_charts examples above and it doesn't work unless you change the list type to: `final List<charts.Series<dynamic, String>> seriesList;` then it will accept the OrdinalSales object or in your case, your custom list of objects.

Your data list could look something like this 

`List data = [
 CustomObj('jour1' : js['jour1']),
 CustomObj('jour2' : js['jour2']),
 CustomObj('jour3' : js['jour3']),
]`